# Powers in homomorphisms proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Proof verification for following statement.

> Suppose $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism of groups. If $g\in G$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $(\phi (g))^n=\phi (g^n)$

**Proof**

Consider $\phi(g^n)$ for $n>0$, $$\phi(g^n)=\phi(\underset{\text{n times}}{\underbrace{g\ast_Gg\ast_G\cdot\cdot\cdot\ast_Gg}})=\underset{\text{n times}}{\underbrace{\phi(g)\ast_H\phi(g)\ast_H\cdot\cdot\cdot\ast_H\phi(g)}}=\phi(g)^n$$

**EDIT** Part above by induction:

$n=1$: This is trivial as clearly $\phi(g^1)=(\phi(g))^1=\phi(g)$

Now assume true for $n=k$ and prove for $n=k+1$. Therefore we have $$\phi(g^{k+1})=\phi(g^{k}\ast_G g)=\phi(g^{k})\ast_H\phi(g)$$ Then from assumption about $k$ we have $$\phi(g^{k})\ast_H\phi(g)=(\phi(g))^{k}\ast_H\phi(g)=(\phi(g))^{k+1}$$ Therefore true for $n>0$

**END OF EDIT**

Now consider $n=0$, such that $g^0=e_G$, $$\phi(e_G)\ast_H\phi(e_G)=\phi(e_G\ast_Ge_G)=\phi(e_G)=e_H\ast_H\phi(e_G)$$ $$\phi(e_G)\ast_H\phi(e_G)=e_H\ast_H\phi(e_G)$$ $$\phi(e_G)=e_H$$

Now consider $n=-1$,
$$\phi(g)\ast_H\phi(g^{-1})=\phi(g\ast_G g^{-1})=\phi(e_G)$$ Therefore  by uniqueness of inverses $$\phi(g^{-1})=(\phi(g))^{-1}$$
Now for $n<0$ we have, $\phi(g^n)=\phi((g^{-n})^{-1})=(\phi(g^{-n}))^{-1}$ from previous. Therefore now as $-n>0$ it follows from the proof of $n>0$ that $$\phi(g^{-n})=(\phi(g))^{-n}$$ $$\therefore \; \phi(g^{n})=(\phi(g^{-n}))^{-1}=(\phi(g))^n \;\;\ \text{for}\; n<0$$ Therefore proved for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Does this look like a good proof, rigorous enough? Any suggestions and comments welcome.

Comment: This part $$\phi(g^n)=\phi(\underset{\text{n times}}{\underbrace{g\ast_Gg\ast_G\cdot\cdot\cdot\ast_Gg}})=\underset{\text{n times}}{\underbrace{\phi(g)\ast_H\phi(g)\ast_H\cdot\cdot\cdot\ast_H\phi(g)}}= \phi(g)^n$$ feels like cheating. I'd prove this part by induction and keep the rest as you've done it.

Answer (score 1):

A proof with "$\ldots$" in it cannot be considered rigorous.
Your idea is correct though, just try to treat the case $n>0$ by induction.

Comment: I've edited my answer, would this suffice as a full proof now?